# Error: "http_archive" is not defined when starting the local Bazel server in the TensorFlow Installation

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, bazel, http-archive

I am installing **Tensorflow.** I encountered the following problem: 
I was installing Tensorflow from Source and I am following the Tensorflow website (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source)

I had earlier installed **Bazel** 3.0.0 (the latest version) but got a similar error. Upon looking at other answers I figured out this error has something to do with the version of Bazel. Hence I uninstalled Bazel 3.0.0 and installed Bazel 0.27.1. But upon typing the following command(`bazel build //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`) in the terminal, I am getting the following error:

```
WARNING: The following rc files are no longer being read, please transfer their contents or import their path into one of the standard rc files:
/home/aviraj/tensorflow/tools/bazel.rc
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
ERROR: /home/aviraj/tensorflow/WORKSPACE:3:1: name 'http_archive' is not defined
ERROR: Error evaluating WORKSPACE file
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'closure/defs.bzl': no such package '@io_bazel_rules_closure//closure': error loading package 'external': Could not load //external package
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'closure/defs.bzl': no such package '@io_bazel_rules_closure//closure': error loading package 'external': Could not load //external package
INFO: Elapsed time: 2.023s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Starting with version 0.20.0, `http_archive` native rule has been deprecated, it has to be loaded from: `@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl`. I.e. you need to add the following (unless you have a customized version) in `WORKSPACE` or `bzl` files using it:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")
```